# How can I connect to server on our network from xamarin debug session on dev machine

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I've written and deployed a asp.net core 2.1 web api REST service to our server on our network, which is hosted in IIS, and sending HTTP requests to the service works using Postman. Now I am writing a Xamarin app which needs to connect to this service. All this will be from within our network, so the server is referenced by name and its IP address is always an internal one. When debugging the app in Visual Studio, I cannot reach the server.

I've added the connectivity Nuget package to the Xam project, and testing for external address is fine, but testing for internal server name or IP address comes back false. I've disabled my firewall but this also has no effect.

```cs
var connectivity = CrossConnectivity.Current;
var google = await connectivity.IsRemoteReachable("216.58.208.99");
var reachable = await connectivity.IsReachable("10.1.1.5");
```

reachable comes back false every time

Comment: This is a networking problem, not a programming one.  You need to do some basic troubleshooting.  Can you reach the server IP using the browser on your test device?

Comment: yes it's only from within the UWP/Android emulator from Visual Studio that I can't access it. Anywhere outside of that is fine

Comment: Android emulator connectivity setup is exhaustively documented, on SO and elsewhere.  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: since I've been testing it in UWP on Local Machine, and that doesn't run in an isolated environment, shouldn't I still be able to resolve the network address?